# Ax 2009 Customer Aging Report

Tags: axapta

AX noob here.

I'd like to change the Customer Aging Report so that in sorts by dollar amount rather than account number. How would I go about this? In the sorting tab, I don't see a value in the Field drop-down that would coincide with the dollar amount columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, it is not possible.

There is no table holding the open balance, hence it is not possible to sort on that value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the MorphX auto query tool.  Click "Select" on the customer aging report window.  Then in the upper section under "Structure" where it shows the customer table.  Right click and do 1:N and choose "Customer Transactions (Customer account)" to join to it.  Then right click on that newly joined table, and choose 1:N and join "Open customer transactions".

Then on the sorting tab, you should be able to sort by the open transactions.

@Jan B. Kjeldsen, isn't the CustTransOpen table used specifically for this?

Comment: This will not work. The CustTransOpen table is joined with "exist join" so sorting will not work. Besides it holds the individual open amount, not the total open amount.